# Why does Floyd Warshall's algorithm succeed?

Tags: algorithm, graph

What is to stop a better intermediate path from being found in a later iteration of the outer loop (loops over all possible intermediate vertices) that goes through an earlier one that was already iterated over?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have a misunderstanding of how the Floyd-Warshall algorithm works. For reference, here's an implementation (from https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/all-pair-shortest-path-floyd-warshall.html):

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            d[i][j] = min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]); 
        }
    }
}
```

The outermost loop does not loop over all intermediate vertices. When computing the shortest path from `i` to `j`, the outermost loop defines the set of vertices that can be a part of the path from `i` to `j`. In particular, if we label our `n` vertices `1, 2, 3, ..., n`, then the value of `k` specifies that we can only visit vertices from the set `{1, 2, ..., k}` on that iteration. You can see that, as `k -> n`, the `d[i][j]` values eventually converge to our solution (since a true "shortest path" should be allowed to use any vertex as an intermediate).

Why do we break it down in this manner? Because if we know the solution for a fixed value of `k`, then we can easily construct the solution for `k + 1`. This is a key principle of dynamic programming, and you should try to understand how the recurrence `d[i][j] = min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j])` exhausts all possibilities.

Now to answer your question directly more directly, it doesn't matter if a newly computed path using the set `{1, 2, ..., k}` uses the results from the previous iteration of the outermost loop. This is true because the set `{1, 2, ..., k - 1}` is a subset of `{1, 2, ..., k}`, so it would be perfectly fine if we did reuse our previously shorted computed path. The key idea is that we have the *option* to use the newly added vertex `k`.